# How to change keyboard shortcuts in Team Web Access 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to change keyboard shortcuts in Web Access ?

(I am using Team Foundation Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2012).

The problem is that **Alt+S** shortcut saves a work item, instead of writing a special character ("ś" in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, there is no such customization.

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775953/adding-new-task-in-tfs-2012-web-access-problem-with-right-alt-s). As you can see, the fix will be shipped with VS Update 2.

[Update 2 Announcment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx)